# How to post JSONObject to RESTful service and read response using java

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am trying to call POST operation of the service with JSON request body and read JSON response.

I have below method to build the JSON request as JSONObject object.

```
public class CashFundTransfer {
public JSONObject buildRequest(){
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    request.put("dateTime", getDateTimeObj());
    request.put("businessDate", getBusinessDateObj());
    request.put("description", getDescriptionObj());
    request.put("transferAccount", buildTransferAccount());
    request.put("amount", buildAmount());
    request.put("businessUnit", buildBusinessUnit());
    request.put("status", buildStatus());
    request.put("recipient", buildRecipient());
    request.put("cashFundTransferee", buildCashFundTransferee());
    request.put("enteringAssoc", buildEnteringAssoc());
    request.put("approvingAssoc", buildApprovingAssoc());
    request.put("accountingDivision", buildAccountingDivision());
    return request;
   }
}
```

All methods that that I call in put return a JSONObject's object that is a child node of the parent.

In my test class, I have the below code. When I execute the code, service is recieving hashcode of the StringEntity object, instead of the content.

```
public class CFTTest {
   CashFundTransfer cft = new CashFundTransfer();
   JSONObject request = cft.buildRequest();
   System.out.println("request: "+request);

   public void callService() throws IOException{
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
          String inputString = request.toString();
          System.out.println("inputString 1: "+inputString);
          StringEntity input = new StringEntity(inputString);
          System.out.println("input: "+input);
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
          input.setContentType("application/json");
          postRequest.setEntity(input);
          try {
               response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.out.println("response: "+response);
      }
}
```

Below is the console when I execute this code.

```
request: {"dateTime":"2016-12-04","businessDate":"2016-12-04","amount":      {"Value":200.0,"currency":{"code":"USD","description":"dollar"}},"businessUnit":{"number":5525,"name":"WMT","location":{"countryCode":"US"},"id":"0"},"recipient":{"name":{"fullName":"Samuel"}},"description":"Store Use 1","transferAccount":{"id":992},"accountingDivision":{"number":"1"},"enteringAssoc":{"id":"0"},"cashFundTransferee":{"id":"0","type":"OPERATOR"},"approvingAssoc":{"id":"0"},"status":{"code":"1"}}
inputString 1: {"dateTime":"2016-12-04","businessDate":"2016-12-04","amount":{"Value":200.0,"currency":{"code":"USD","description":"dollar"}},"businessUnit":{"number":5525,"name":"WMT","location":{"countryCode":"US"},"id":"0"},"recipient":{"name":{"fullName":"Samuel"}},"description":"Store Use 1","transferAccount":{"id":992},"accountingDivision":{"number":"1"},"enteringAssoc":{"id":"0"},"cashFundTransferee":{"id":"0","type":"OPERATOR"},"approvingAssoc":{"id":"0"},"status":{"code":"1"}}
input: org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@737996a0
14:06:22.238 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Get    connection for route {s}-   >https://nodejs.dev.cashfundtransfer.bofbua.prod.cloud.wal-mart.com
14:06:22.506 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to nodejs.dev.cashfundtransfer.bofbua.prod.cloud.wal-mart.com:443
14:06:22.609 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
14:06:22.630 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache   not set in the context
14:06:22.630 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:06:22.631 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:06:22.631 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
14:06:22.632 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /api/cashfundtransfer/v1 HTTP/1.1
14:06:22.632 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "POST /api/cashfundtransfer/v1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.634 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Length: 475[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.634 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.634 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: nodejs.dev.cashfundtransfer.bofbua.prod.cloud.wal-mart.com[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.634 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /api/cashfundtransfer/v1 HTTP/1.1
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 475
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: nodejs.dev.cashfundtransfer.bofbua.prod.cloud.wal-mart.com
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
14:06:22.635 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.5 (java 1.5)
14:06:22.636 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "{"dateTime":"2016-12-04","businessDate":"2016-12-04","amount":{"Value":200.0,"currency":{"code":"USD","description":"dollar"}},"businessUnit":{"number":5525,"name":"WMT","location":{"countryCode":"US"},"id":"0"},"recipient":{"name":{"fullName":"Samuel"}},"description":"Store Use 1","transferAccount":{"id":992},"accountingDivision":{"number":"1"},"enteringAssoc":{"id":"0"},"cashFundTransferee":{"id":"0","type":"OPERATOR"},"approvingAssoc":{"id":"0"},"status":{"code":"1"}}"
14:06:22.653 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.658 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "x-frame-options: DENY[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "x-download-options: noopen[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "x-content-type-options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "cache-control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.660 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "content-length: 197[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.660 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 20:06:23 GMT[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.660 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.660 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << x-frame-options: DENY
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << x-download-options: noopen
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << x-content-type-options: nosniff
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << cache-control: no-cache
14:06:22.661 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << content-length: 197
14:06:22.662 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 20:06:23 GMT
14:06:22.662 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Connection: keep-alive
14:06:22.667 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8, strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000, x-frame-options: DENY, x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block, x-download-options: noopen, x-content-type-options: nosniff, cache-control: no-cache, content-length: 197, Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 20:06:23 GMT, Connection: keep-alive]
```

Unable to identify, where I am going wrong on this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `JSONObject.toString()` does not returns a json string. You need to use `JSONObject.toJSONString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that JSONObject comes from the JSON.simple third party (You should probably add this information in the question next time, as java does not have any standard way to deal with json, yet).

You need to invoke `JSONObject.toJSONString()` to retrieve the json string, as such:

```
String inputString = request.toJSONString();
System.out.printf("inputString 1: %s\n", inputString);
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(inputString);
```

Also, when dealing with web services, content types should match the content of the request. If you use the `StringEntity` constructor with a single parameter, apache http client will assume the `text/plain` content type, which is incorrect. You should use:

```
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(inputString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: That also goes for your post.  I noticed your `Content-Type` is `text/plain`. Call `postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")`

Comment: @sturcotte06 I made both the changes, but I don't see any change in behavior. When I run it in debug, at `postRequest.setEntity(input);` value in input reflects the hashcode, not the JSON body.

Answer (score 0):

It failed because of a typo in my request object. Its working fine now.